# Do I have legal recourse for suspected financial fraud?(US)

Tags: united-states, consumer-protection, fraud

I have a tenant whom for the last 23 months has been depositing their rent into our bank account with no issues. This month, however, their rent was deposited and then immediately withdrawn from my account. They are not joint account holders. My tenant indicated that she was given two receipts for both the deposit and withdrawal. She did not realize it until I reached out to her. She indicated that the teller was new. My concern is that my tenant whom should not have access to withdrawal money was able to withdrawal and was likely given a receipt containing how much money was in my account. Is there a legal recourse in this situation against the financial institution for the following: allow unauthorized person to withdrawal from my account and failing to complete the proper controls and providing protected personal information to an unauthorized person?

To preface we only gave our tenant the last four numbers of our account and our name for them to deposit rent into our account.

Comment: You only have legal recourse for actual financial fraud. Suspecting it isn't enough. A bank employee error that does you no long term actual harm because the rent is ultimately paid isn't something you can sue over.

Answer (score 1):

If you can prove that there was actual fraud (false representation in order to induce agreement to do something), then if you suffered a loss as a consequence of having been deceived, you can sue the defrauding party. Nothing in your description resembles fraud in the slightest. Next up to bat in the world of lawsuits would be negligence, where the bank's actions caused you to suffer a loss. Somewhere in that same vicinity would be breach of contract. These are the things where you personally might have legal recourse, and they depend on you having suffered a loss of some sort. I assume that the error was corrected and the money is back in your account.

The government might get involved in two ways. First, the government prosecutes people for committing a crime, but you haven't described any crime. Another is that there might be a civil penalty issued against a regulated business, for violating a regulation. The Federal Reserve System is the primary federal regulatory agency for banks, but there could be many governmental agencies with regulatory power. It is possible that the bank can be punished for this action, in particular for violation of the FTC's Financial Privacy Rule. [This page](https://www.fdic.gov/regulations/laws/rules/index.html) compiles links to various FDIC regulations. At the level of basic bank operations such as "only *I* get access to the account", this is probably governed by state law, as in [these](https://dfi.wa.gov/banks/laws-rules) Washington state laws. So it is possible that there is a regulatory penalty for whatever the teller did.